# What should I use instead of PostgreSQL11Dialect?

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, postgresql-11

I am using Hibernate 5 and PostgreSQL 11. I checked [dialects](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/) and the latest is `PostgreSQL95Dialect`.

What should I use with a newer version of the database I have?

I assume that there is no major problem using `PostgreSQL95Dialect` but it sounds wrong for me, especially database may further upgrade and the closer versions can be updated more seamlessly in the future.

*Reason:*

The reason, I care about dialects, I want to introduce new type `jsonb` which is not supported by Hibernate, so I want to be as close to the contemporary version of a DB as possible, dialect-wise as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you plan to use PostgreSQL 11 features you probably should implement the dialect yourself.

In Hibernate 6.0 new [`PostgreSQL10Dialect`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/76981d97a87a50814835124c86d8a428f0129245/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL10Dialect.java) was introduced. When implementing your own `PostgreSQL11Dialect` you probably want to follow the same approach, which is extending `PostgreSQL95Dialect` and adding features you need.

Comment: Meh, 10 just adds identity columns. The PG dialects are still missing tons of stuff like ts functions etc...

Answer (score 2):

Latest in the official hibernate GitHub repository is [PostgreSQL10Dialect](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL10Dialect.java). However, this one is still not referenced in the [latest official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html).